# How to add NaN for missing data while appending data?

Tags: python, pandas, append, missing-data

I have a function, like below:

```
    def fsheet_DCOP(s,j,k,l):

        ret=pd.DataFrame([])
        j=j[j[3].str.contains(s,na=False)]
        for i in k:
            ret=ret.append(j[j[5] == i])

        ret=ret[ret[7]==l]

        ret=ret[:1] 
        return ret
```

Sometimes in the dataframe that gets passed, there is no match found in column 5 or column 7.

In this case, how can I fill a row with a NaN value or a default value like '0'?

I have other functions that access value returned by above function, and it cannot have empty dataframe.

For example when the input parameters passed are as below:
data frame j is

```
   3     5   7     9
0  red   sq  side  100
1  blue  ci  rad   4
2  green re  lb    43
3  red   ci  side  53
4  blue  sq  side  2.1
5  red   sq  side  1.1

s='red'
k='sq'
l='side'
```

It will return  ret as

```
print(fsheet_DCOP(s,j,k,l))

   9
0  100
5  1.1
```

But when
s='yellow'

there is no match for yellow in the data frame j's column 3, so it will return an empty data frame.
Instead of this, how can I append a 0 everytime there is no match?
So that

```
print(fsheet_DCOP(s,j,k,l))

   9
0  0
5  0
```

Comment: Please add some data to test and reproduce the issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi @anky_91,  I have added a sample set of arguments and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

As it became apparent, there is no option or method to check if the value is null at the same time as appending.
So, here is my workaround:
Before the function returns the ret variable, add check if ret is empty ad fill it with some NaN values.

```
import numpy as np
    .
    .
    .
   def fsheet_DCOP(s,j,k,l):
           .
           .
           .
            if(ret.empty):
               ret=pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=[0], columns=[0,24])
            return ret
```